# Unnest Facebook Ads JSON with Python

Tags: python, json

I have some JSON data like:

```
[
    {
        "adset_id": "23851149362570451",
        "reach": "862",
        "clicks": "1",
        "actions": [
            {
                "action_type": "post_reaction",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "action_type": "post_engagement",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "action_type": "page_engagement",
                "value": "1"
            }
        ],
        "date_start": "2022-10-06",
    },
]
```

In the actual data, this array would contain around 30 or 40 objects; I have shown just one for reference.

How can I flatten everything inside the "actions" array, so that it looks like this instead?

```
[
    {
        "adset_id": "23851149362570451",
        "reach": "862",
        "clicks": "1",
        "post_reaction" : "1",
        "post_engagement" : "1",
        "page_engagement" : "1",
        "date_start": "2022-10-06",
    },
]
```

Comment: What should happen if `actions` contains more than one action **of the same `action_type`**? (This is probably **why** the API chose to organize the data this way in the first place.)

Comment: Hi Karl... thanks for your attention.

I haven't seen a reason why API send the same action_type twice just because i'm breaking down by day and ad... so basically they do return the actions an ad had that specific day.

The way i see, there is no reason why the API should return the same metric/action_type twice for the same ad.

Does it make sense to you as well?

Comment: I don't know the API or what its purpose is. I only know that decisions like these are usually made to plan in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly wrote this. Modify it as per how you ingest the data:

```
import json

final_result = []
with open('data.json') as f:
    api_data_dict = json.load(f)
    for api_data_obj in api_data_dict:
        actions = []
        values = []
        updated_actions = {}
        
        #assuming there are objects with action_type and value present inside this dict
        for action in api_data_obj['actions']:
            actions.append(action['action_type'])
            values.append(action['value'])
        
        for action, value in zip(actions, values):
            updated_actions[action] = value
        api_data_obj.pop('actions', None)
        final_result.append({**api_data_obj, **updated_actions})
        
print(final_result)
```

`data.json` contents:

```
[{

    "adset_id": "23851149362570451",
    "reach": "862",
    "clicks": "1",
    "actions": [
        {
            "action_type": "post_reaction",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "post_engagement",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "page_engagement",
            "value": "1"
        }
    ],
    "date_start": "2022-10-06"
},
{

    "adset_id": "234543535643543",
    "reach": "862",
    "clicks": "1",
    "actions": [
        {
            "action_type": "post_reaction",
            "value": "2"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "post_engagement",
            "value": "2"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "page_engagement",
            "value": "2"
        }
    ],
    "date_start": "2022-10-06"
}]
```

Result:

```
[
   {
      "adset_id":"23851149362570451",
      "reach":"862",
      "clicks":"1",
      "date_start":"2022-10-06",
      "post_reaction":"1",
      "post_engagement":"1",
      "page_engagement":"1"
   },
   {
      "adset_id":"234543535643543",
      "reach":"862",
      "clicks":"1",
      "date_start":"2022-10-06",
      "post_reaction":"2",
      "post_engagement":"2",
      "page_engagement":"2"
   }
]
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil... really appreciate your help!

I got the logic, and seems good.. but it is returning an erro like: *KeyError: 'actions'*

I simply changed the line *with open('data.json') as f:* to add the json path.. nothing else. 

Was that your intention (update the json path) with the comment "Modify it as per how you ingest the data:"

The data structure is the same described before.

An extra help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: @RodrigoWiethorn what is the source of your JSON data? It is an API url or a data file? This has been written assuming that the data is being read from a `data.json` which has the structure (array of objects) as given above (after the code).

Comment: The data is a JSON file with the same structure i've described previously. have the script worked on your end?